# Object Oriented Programming and Classes in Python

Tags: class, oop, python-2.7

These are the instructions I was given:

> Create a Point class that consists of an ordered pair (x, y) representing a point's location on the x and y axes. The constructor allow the x and y values to be passed in and should default missing values to 0. You must override the **str** method to print the point as normal (i.e., "(2, 5)").

Also, create a Line class that consists of a pair of Point objects p and q. A line can be instantiated in one of two ways, as shown below.

```
somePoint = Point(2, 3)   
anotherPoint = Point(4, 8)
someLine = Line(somePoint, anotherPoint)
```

or...

```
someLine = Line()
```

In the second case, the constructor should initialize both points to the origin `(0, 0)`. You must override the `__str__` method to print the line as follows: `(2, 5)--(4, 7)`. Your class must also provide a length method that returns the
length of the segment.

### This is the module file

```
import final
somePoint = final.Point(4, 5)
anotherPoint = final.Point(5, 7)
someList = final.Line(somePoint, anotherPoint)
distance = final.Line.distance(someList)
```

### My code so far

```
import math


class Point():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xy = [x, y]
        self.printer = ("(" + str(x) + "," + str(y) + ")")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.printer)


class Line():

    def __init__(self, p, q):
        self.coor = [p, q]
        self.pq = (str(p) + "--" + str(q)) #<--------- From here down is where I'm having trouble.

    def distance(self):

        self.x1 = self.coor[0][0]
        self.x2 = self.coor[1][0]
        self.y1 = self.coor[0][1]
        self.y2 = self.coor[1][1]

        self.xdiff = math.fabs(int(self.x1) - int(self.x2))
        self.ydiff = math.fabs(int(self.y1) - int(self.y2))
        self.xsq = (self.xdiff ** 2)
        self.ysq = (self.ydiff ** 2)
        self.distance = float(math.sqrt(self.xsq + self.ysq))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pq) + "the distance of that line is " + str(self.distance)
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1.) The `distance` function has an error. The first four lines should be:

```
self.x1 = self.coor[0].xy[0]
self.x2 = self.coor[1].xy[0]
self.y1 = self.coor[0].xy[1]
self.y2 = self.coor[1].xy[1]
```

2.) The `distance` function does not return anything, so the `distance` variable in the main file, will have the value `None`. Add a return statement to the function.

3.) You should fix the string representation for `Line`.

4.) The requirements state that the parameters for `Point` and `Line` should be optional. Make them optional by giving them default values.

Answer (score 0):

If the Point class must be initialized in the coordinates (0, 0) by default, the constructor must be:

```
class Point():

def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.xy = [x, y]
    self.printer = ("(" + str(x) + "," + str(y) + ")")
# ...
```

After, the constructor of Line class must get two Point instances in the constructor, and by default, similar to the previous class definition, you must have something like

```
class Line():
    def __init__(self, p=Point(), q=Point()):
        self.x1 = p.xy[0]
        self.y1 = p.xy[1]
        self.x2 = q.xy[0]
        self.y2 = q.xy[1]

    def distance(self):
        return math.sqrt((self.x1-self.x2)**2 + (self.y1 - self.y2)**2)
```

The definition of the **str** override method is bad. If you want something like your problem use

```
    def __str__(self):
        return str('(' + str(self.x1) + ', ' + str(self.x2) + ')--(' + str(self.x2) + ', ' + str(self.y2) + ')')
```